# Estoy queriendo mostrar un texto en un campo de mi formulario pero quiero guardar en este campo otro valor

Tags: formularios, symfony

chicos necesito que me ayuden. Estoy queriendo mostrar un texto en un campo de mi formulario pero quiero guardar en este campo otro valor, se puede hacer??? utilizo symfony 3.1, este es mi codigo:

```
{{ form_widget(form.entidad,{'attr':{'class': 'form-control','id':'entidad', 'value': ent.id}} ) }}
{{ form_errors(form.entidad) }}
```

necesito guardar el id, pero mostrar el nombre algo asi: 'value': ent.nombre

Comment: Teoría sobre formularios HTML5. Puedes usar un atributo de tipo `data-*` en tu *input* para almacenar un dato diferente del que guarde `value`. Sería `'data-id': ent.id` dentro de los atributos que estas definiendo.

Comment: muchas gracias, pero lo hice y el valor que trata de insertar en la base de datos es el string, me da el siguiente error: Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\Entidad" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\Anexo9#$identidad", got "string" instead.

Comment: No he trabajado con symfony, no se decirte. Otra opción para guardar datos adicionales es usar campos de tipo oculto.

Answer (score 0):

Al tratarse de una entidad, al construir el formulario, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$builder
  ->add('entidad', EntityType::class, [
      'class' => Entidad::class,
      'label'  => 'Entidad',
      'choice_label' => 'nombre', // <- El texto que se muestra como opción es el nombre
      'choice_value' => 'id', // <- El valor que se manda al controlador al enviar el formulario es el id
      'empty_data' => '',
      'required' => true,
      'attr' => [
          'class' => 'form-controll'
      ]
  ]);
```

De esta forma, haces que sea el propio symfony el que controla que la opción mandada hacia el controlador sea un ID válido.

Espero que te sirva, saludos.